# Undefined class/module in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, delayed-job

I created map_job.rb in project lib folder. But why I am getting this error when delayed job.

- error message

  "last_error": "Job failed to load: undefined class/module MapJob. Handler: \"---  !ruby/struct:MapJob\nid: aa\n\"\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:87:in `rescue in payload_object'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:85:in`payload_object'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:95:in `block in invoke_job'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in`call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in`call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in`run_callbacks'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:92:in `invoke_job'\n(eval):3:in`block in invoke_job_with_newrelic_transaction_trace'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.2.239/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:365:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'\n(eval):2:in`invoke_job_with_newrelic_transaction_trace'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:203:in `block (2 levels) in run'\n/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in`timeout'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:203:in `block in run'\n/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in`realtime'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:202:in `run'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:259:in`block in reserve_and_run_one_job'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in`block in initialize'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in`execute'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:259:in`reserve_and_run_one_job'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:187:in `block in work_off'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in`times'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in `work_off'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:151:in`block (4 levels) in start'\n/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:150:in`block (3 levels) in start'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in`block in initialize'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in`execute'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:149:in`block (2 levels) in start'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:148:in `loop'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:148:in`block in start'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in`block (2 levels) in '\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in`block (2 levels) in add'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in`block in initialize'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in`block in add'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in`execute'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:147:in`start'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in`call'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in`each'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'\n/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in`invoke_with_call_chain'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in`invoke_task'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`each'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`run_with_threads'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`block in run'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`run'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'\n/app/vendor/bundle /ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in`load'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `'",

Please help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to autoload map_job.rb

Do this in your application.rb file and restart your server.

```
require "#{Rails.root.to_s}/lib/map_job.rb"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class/Module named MapJob in your map_job.rb file?. The Error complains that you have not defined a class/module with that name

Comment: Name of the file is map_job.rb and inside this file I used class MapJob "class MapJob < Struct.new(:id)
  def perform
  end
end"